# SearchView crashes with inflation error (androidx) - resource not found exception

Tags: android, searchview, androidx

I have a `SearchView` in one of my layouts and get appended crash on *some* devices. The problem is that the `abc_textfield_search_material` resource is not found. But I'm not using this resource directly, as my xml layout simply looks like following:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/svSearch"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="@string/filter"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        app:queryHint="@string/filter" />
```

Any ideas how to solve this? This crash happens on rare devices only (less than 1%), most devices simply work. I'm already thinking about changing this to a `TextView` with a compound drawable instead but maybe there's a better solution than just avoiding to use a `SearchView`

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.my.app/com.my.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4071)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4026)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3978)
    at android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.execute(PauseActivityItem.java:45)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1818)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6744)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    ...
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.my.app:drawable/abc_textfield_search_material with resource ID #0x7f080058
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_textfield_search_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080058
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:847)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:631)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:888)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:827)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:635)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.a(ContextCompat.java:463)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.a(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.a(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.b(AppCompatResources.java:102)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.a(TintTypedArray.java:76)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:298)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:270)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    ...
```

**Theme**

I'm using an android x theme in my app - `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge`

**Affected devises (I know of)**

- One Plus 7 Pro (GM1913, GM1915, GM1917)
- Samsung S9+ Korea (SM-G965N)

Comment: If you use androidx, you should also be using corresponding material themes.

Comment: so you are not using `abc_textfield_search_material` anywhere in the activity ?

Comment: I use the bridge theme currently because of a library I use (`Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge`), this should be fine as well, shouldn't it? It works on most devices. And I don't use `abc_textfield_search_material` anywhere directly, it is accessed within the `SearchView` internal inflation (it comes from `SearchView.<init>`)

Comment: can you add your dependencies?

Comment: The crash happens with me also on very rare devices...

Comment: Considering that `abc_textfield_search_material` is part of the [Android SDK](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_textfield_search_material.xml), this might be a problem with the specific systems that you are deploying to instead of something wrong on your end.

Comment: I have about 50 crashes with 10000 users, quite a lot for a simple default ui element - if this really lies in the system those users use I would say this ui element should be avoided completely... As I don't have any better solution I will have to switch to a custom solution based on an `EditText`...

Comment: was this working before and you build the new app with android studio 3.3.2 and it started crashing ?

Comment: @prom85 I have reported an issue to google here. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141825195. Can you please star it and comment to make it noticed?

Comment: @IslamSalah I have reported an issue to google here. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141825195. Can you please star it and comment to make it noticed?

Answer (score 1):

it complains about:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
Drawable com.my.app:drawable/abc_textfield_search_material with resource ID #0x7f080058

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
File res/drawable/abc_textfield_search_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080058
```

Which *should be* contained in the [androidx.appcompat](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/appcompat/res/drawable/abc_textfield_search_material.xml) `1.0.2` library itself.

Adding that resource directly into the app's resources might possibly help;

along with `@drawable/abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha`

and `@drawable/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha`.

`Resources$NotFoundException` can have various reasons ...

but "individual destinies" < 1% does not tell which devices nor which API level.

a) [view & restrict your app's compatible devices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en) could easily rid you of them.

b) filing an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192731) might be the other option; if possible with said device details.

Comment: As you said, androidx should contain this resource - so shouldn't this crash be device independent which it apperantly isn't? Additionally, it seems not many developers do have this issue, which makes me wondering - I only have less than 100 thousands users and have more than a handful of those crashes...

Comment: I am having same issue with Nexus 6(motorola) with Android version 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

For now I ended up using something like this instead of the `SearchView`:

https://github.com/droidparts/droidparts/blob/master/droidparts-misc/src/org/droidparts/widget/ClearableEditText.java

A simple `EditText` with `CompoundDrawable` and touch listener for this clear icon...

Still, if someone finds a solution to the problem let me know please.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution it's not a bug from the android, you have to use AppCompat theme in order to use SearchView, so add any "Theme.AppCompat" theme and your problem is solved, you didn't able to set because of huge code, then go to their layout file(searchview) and in thier parent add

```
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

make sure that theme have Theme.AppCompat